# Java: won't compile - incompatible types that must be compatible

Tags: java, generics, casting

This code will not compile, and I don't understand why.  The error is at the indicated line:

```
   static <T extends DB> T createModelObjectFromCopy(T fromRow) {
            T mo = null;
            try {
   -->          mo = fromRow.getClass().newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBTypes.Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return Table.initializeFromCopy(mo, fromRow);
        }
    }
```

`fromRow` is a value object that wraps immutable types.

From the declaration it is clear that `fromRow` must be of type `T`.  The variable `mo` must be of the very same type `T`.

Why can the reflectively instantiated new instance not be assigned to `mo`?  I assume that the class object returned by `fromRow.getClass()` is `Class<T>` and that `newInstance()` -should- instantiate a new instance of `T`.

Comment: You should pass `Class<T> clazz` as argument to your method.

Comment: The method was originally written this way, but since `fromRow` is already an instance of `T`, I thought that I could just use `getClass()` instead.  It seems like it ought to be valid.

Comment: Since `fromRow` can always refer to an instance of any subclass of `T`, `getClass` cannot return `Class<T>`, instead it's `Class<? extends T>`.

Comment: Do you really need generics here? Just remove generics and use DB.

Comment: @nomoa: For this method, there are many possible `T`'s, all of which extend the interface DB.  The instance created by this method needs to match the particular subtype.

Comment: @scottb: yes so why not : static DB createModelObjectFromCopy(DB fromRow). It will work you'll just have to cast (if needed) on the caller. Trying to avoid this cast with generics will lead to warnings in java code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `fromRow.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends DB>`, not `Class<T>`: the compiler does not know enough to make the inference.

Since you know that the result is going to be of the correct type, you could use cast to force the conversion. There are two ways of doing this:

```
Class<T> cl = (Class<T>)fromRow.getClass();
mo = cl.newInstance();
```

or

```
mo = (T)fromRow.getClass().newInstance();
```

Comment: In fact `newInstance()` will return `? extends DB` - because type erasure indeed looses the type, but not what it was bound to (DB).

Comment: `fromRow.getClass()` actually returns `Class<? extends DB>`. See the documentation for `getClass()` "The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called."

Comment: This all explains it ... still ... -I- can look at this code and clearly see that the assignment can not fail because the types must be the same.  It's only the run-time type that is <? extends DB>. It seems like the compiler ought to be able to see this as well: `fromRow` is `T`, `mo` is `T` ... everything is type `T`.

Comment: @scottb `mo` is `T`, `fromRow` is `T`, but it's not necessarily the case that `mo.getClass() == fromRow.getClass()`! In other words, we know that `mo` can be assigned to a `T`, and `fromRow` can be assigned to a `T`, but the compiler doesn't know that `mo = fromRow` is valid based on declared types.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) - runtime the JVM won't know the type of `fromRow`; at the indicated point of code what the JVM (compiler) can only assume is that it is something that may extend DB. Hence you need to do what is suggested in the other answers (cast or pass the exact type).